# React router dom render different route based on parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am currently developing a react app with an admin dashboard that has different "tabs" that I integrated them in a Router. After the admin logs in, the app navigates you to `/admin`. The idea of that page is that I have a side menu with different pages. Inside the `AdminView` I want to display the specific component based on the id that I provide:

Here is the main route that displays the admin view

```
<Route path="/admin">
   <Route path="login" element={<AdminLogin />} />
   <Route path=":page" element={<AdminView />} />
</Route>
```

Inside the Admin view I have something like this:

I am selecting the component that I want to display based in the `:page`:

```
  const getTable = () => {
    switch (table) {
      case 'realms':
        return RealmsTable;
      case 'clients':
        return ClientsTable;
      case 'users':
        return UsersTable;
      case 'roles':
        return RolesTable;
      case 'management':
        return Management;
      default:
        return NotFoundtView;
    }
  };

  const Table = useMemo(getTable, [table]);
```

With that component selected I am displaying it like so:

```
    <Layout className="dashboard-layout" hasSider>
      <DSider />
      <Layout>
        <DHeader />
        <Content>
          <Suspense>
            <Routes>
              <Route index Component={Table} />
            </Routes>
          </Suspense>
        </Content>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
```

This is doing what I want, but I feel like I am doing it wrong. Is there a cleaner way?

As a reference:

I am using `react 18` and `react-router-dom v6`

More info:

I mentioned a sider that is in sync with the selected table:

```
const { table } = useParams();
return (
    <Sider>
      <Menu
        className="no-bg"
        items={items}
        onClick={onMenuSelect}
        mode="inline"
        defaultSelectedKeys={[table!]}
        inlineCollapsed={collapsed}
        theme="dark"
      ></Menu>
    </Sider>
  );
```

It's a basic `antd` `Menu` component here and I am using the id as the keys for the menu items:

```
const items: MenuItem[] = [
  {
    type: 'divider',
    className: 'menu-devider'
  },
  {
    key: 'realms',
    label: 'Realms',
    className: 'menu-item',
    icon: <ReactSVG src="/svg/realms.svg" />
  },
  {
    type: 'divider',
    className: 'menu-devider'
  },
  {
    key: 'clients',
    label: 'Clients',
    className: 'menu-item',
    icon: <ReactSVG src="/svg/clients.svg" />
  },
  {
    type: 'divider',
    className: 'menu-devider'
  },
  {
    key: 'users',
    label: 'Users',
    className: 'menu-item',
    icon: <ReactSVG src="/svg/users.svg" />
  },
  {
    type: 'divider',
    className: 'menu-devider'
  },
  {
    key: 'roles',
    label: 'Roles',
    className: 'menu-item',
    icon: <ReactSVG src="/svg/roles.svg" />
  },
  {
    type: 'divider',
    className: 'menu-devider'
  },
  {
    key: 'management',
    label: 'Management',
    className: 'menu-item',
    icon: <ReactSVG src="/svg/management.svg" />
  },
  {
    type: 'divider',
    className: 'menu-devider'
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to make `AdminView` a layout route component that renders an `Outlet` component instead of an index route and each table component on its own nested route. This should remove the need for the `getTable` component matcher and component reference memoization. In other words, let React-Router do the matching/rendering work ***for*** you, no need to "re-invent the wheel".

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Layout className="dashboard-layout" hasSider>
  <DSider />
  <Layout>
    <DHeader />
    <Content>
      <Suspense>
        <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
      </Suspense>
    </Content>
  </Layout>
</Layout>
```

```
<Route path="/admin">
  <Route path="login" element={<AdminLogin />} />
  <Route element={<AdminView />}>
    <Route path="realms" element={<RealmsTable />} />
    <Route path="clients" element={<ClientsTable />} />
    <Route path="users" element={<UsersTable />} />
    <Route path="roles" element={<RolesTable />} />
    <Route path="management" element={<RealmsTable />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundtView />} />
</Route>
```

Comment: I will try this later today and tell you the result. For my case I still need to sync the sider menu with the path( I will add the code for that too in an update). We shall see.
Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @Andy95 In the sidebar component you could probably use the [useMatch](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match) hook with path pattern `"/admin/:table"`, e.g. `const match = useMatch("/admin/:table");`, and if there is a match access `match?.params.table` to get the table value.

Comment: And using your solution for that?

Comment: @Andy95 Yes, sorry if that wasn't clear. The `useMatch` is a way to get the path segment as a dynamic value in the sidebar while the main router works as I've suggested.